# How to decrement/decrease a seat value in a booking form?

Tags: php, mysqli, registration

I was wondering how you can decrease a seating value using php/mysqli?

I have setup a basic sessions timetable with customer registration and I wish to display the number seats left (or maximum seating) and have it decrease with each registration of a customer.

Thanks!

I have created a seating row in topics and have a page that displays speakers with topics and session times.

below is the registration php code currently.

```
if (isset($_POST['Name'])) {
            $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Name']);
            $Address = $_POST['Address'];
            $Phone = $_POST['Email'];
            $Email = $_POST['Phone'];           
            $sql = "insert into registration (Name, Address, Email, Phone) values ('$Name','$Address','$Phone','$Email')";
            //echo $sql;
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            // get id from last query insert statement auto increment
            $RegistrationID = mysqli_insert_id($con); 
            foreach($_POST['time'] as $sessionsID){
              echo $sessionsID;
              $sql = "insert into bookings (sessionsID, RegistrationID) values ($sessionsID, $RegistrationID)";
              echo $sql;
              mysqli_query($con, $sql);


            }



                       <?php
                           $sql3 = "select Time, SessionID FROM sessions LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//  $i++;
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value='.$row['SessionID'].' name="time[]">'.$row['Time'].'</label>';


}               
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I'd take:

1. Create a table (or add to an existing one, depending your DB structure) with a column that contains the number of seats.
2. Call it from the db into a variable, eg. `$seat`, at every registration.
3. Make it `$seat--;` (decrement by one), or just `$seat = $seat - 1;`.
4. Update the DB with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you using seat count anywhere. When you have inserted an entry for a ticket confirmed at the same time you have to update the seat count available by subtracting the no of seat booked.

For easy implementation do like this:

1. Select count of ticket booked.
2. Update the remaining seat count by total-booked. Do it for each insert of a ticket booked.